# @ResourceDependency with correct configuration does not find the resource

Tags: single-page-application, jsf-2.2, custom-component

I have a javascript file under the following folder in my JAR component:
**/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/default/javascript/jquery.marquee.js**

If I create a custom JSF component with the following **@ResourceDependency** annotation:

```
@ResourceDependency(library = "default", name = "javascript/jquery.marquee.js", target = "head")
```

The javascript file cannot be found, and in the browser I can see **two** weird URLs with **undefined.css** and **undefined.js** as part of the URL, and also referring the PrimeFaces library ??

```
http://localhost:8080/acio/javax.faces.resource/undefined/undefined.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=5.3
http://localhost:8080/acio/javax.faces.resource/undefined/undefined.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=5.3
```

However, if I manually include the script in a XHTML template as follows:

```
<h:outputScript library="default" name="javascript/jquery.marquee.js" />
```

Then everything works like a charm as expected, with the expected URL as follows:

```
http://localhost:8080/acio/javax.faces.resource/javascript/jquery.marquee.js.xhtml?ln=default
```

I'm completely puzzled about this.

Why, if I use the *@ResourceDependency* annotation, I get **TWO** wrong URL's, one about a CSS and another about the JS, related to the PrimeFaces resources, when I'm positively sure the placement of my own JS file is correct? (otherwise the ***h:outputScript*** would not work as well)

Tested with Mojarra 2.2.13.SP1 shipped with WildFly 10.1.0.Final, and Mojarra 2.2.12 shipped with WildFly 9.0.2.Final

Any help would be greatly appreaciated !

**[UPDATE]**

It looks like the the issue may be related to the way we handle page navigation. We are using a SPA approach, with a Facelet template that has a big panel group area inside, with a dynamic JSF ***include*** directive. Pages are XHTML fragments that are dynamically included in the template's panel group after an AJAX execution.

It appears that **@ResourceDependency** only renders the corresponding HTML resource link when a View is created the very first time. As we are using SPA, our View never changes, from the JSF point of view. We handle all the page navigation with AJAX fragment updates using the ***include*** directive.

As a test, I placed the tag of my component in the Facelet template itself, instead of a XHTML fragment... and the link is rendered as expected !

It would be great if someone can confirm this behaviour... and if there's any elegant solution to it.

So far, we have to manually include the needed HTML resources on the template definition.

Comment: Thanks Kukeltje.  I'm clear about how to use h:outputScript. I have updated my question. No matter which approach I take, it always works.   The problem only happens when trying to include the javascript automatically with my component using the @ResourceDependency annotation.  In that case the javascript cannot be included.  I still cannot understand what's wrong here...

Comment: I have updated my question with the URL's when using @ResourceDependency and when using outputScript.  YES they are DIFFERENT.  But the question is ... WHY ????

Comment: Can you try in a project without PrimeFaces? Can you try PF 6.1? Maybe the PF 'head renderer' screws things up. (just 'guessing', no time to try to replicate myself) Or did your component extend a PrimeFaces base component?

Comment: Yes my component extends from Widget class, and the renderer extends from CoreRenderer ... but ... I figured out a possible cause... I'm using an SPA approach, where pages are just XHTML fragments updated via AJAX on a panel group with a JSF include directive. It looks like the @ResourceDependency annotation does not work at all if the component is used inside such an SPA fragment.  If I use the component on the JSF template, which is rendered the very first time the View is created... then it works fine as expected... I will try to update my question with these findings later on.

Comment: what if you don't use `target = "head"`  on the @ResourceDependency? but e.g. `target="body"` or @this or parent or...

Comment: Good suggestion ... I will have a test ... to be honest, I didn't know what kind of values could be used in the target attribute ...

Comment: From what I read you can even put EL in there

Comment: Seems no matter what I specify as "target" , the problem is always there... where is the PrimeFaces "head" renderer ? Maybe I can have a look ...

Comment: it is in the PrimeFaces github repository (afaik). No tilme/means to look it up know for you, sorry

Comment: Upgrading to PF 6.1 solves the problem automatically ...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem goes away when upgrading to PrimeFaces 6.1. Probably Kukeltje is right, and the PF 5.3 Resource Renderer has some kind of bug.

In short, when developing your own JSF PrimeFaces components, PF 5.3 will not render the @ResourceDependency annotations of the JSF component in some situations, like the one described here: using an SPA approach with XHTML fragments.

Moving to PF 6.1 solves the problem. If upgrading is not possible, we have to manually include the needed JS / CSS resources in the fragment with outputScript tags.